# Why am I missing arrows from my last two chat bubbles?

Tags: html, css, chat

I am building a chat transcript from a psd file. So far I have everything down to point except my last two chat bubbles are missing their arrows. See pic and code below.

[image]

You see the first two have their arrows point to the users and last two are missing. I am looking for anyone can point me into the right direction of how to get the arrows for the last two chat bubbles.

```css
* {
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

section {
  width: 850px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 5%;
  // margin-bottom: 15.7%;
}

.header li {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.header .header-title {
  width: 220px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 3.9px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  left: -6%;
}

.header .header-date {
  width: 240px;
  height: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: right;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  position: relative;
  right: -5%;
}

.line {
  width: 750px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.chat-log {
  margin-bottom: 5%
}

#user1 {
  width: 100%;
}

#user1 ul li.avatar img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.message-box {
  height: 100%;
}

#user1 ul li.message .message-box {
  width: 610px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#user1 ul li.message .message-box:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #f3f3f3;
  right: 66.1%;
  top: 37%;
}

#user2 {
  width: 100%;
}

#user2 ul {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#user2 ul li.avatar img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#user2 ul li.message .message-box {
  width: 610px;
  // height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#user2 ul li.message .message-box:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  left: 66.1%;
  top: 61%;
}

#user2 .message-box .text-bottom .user-name {
  color: #5da2ff;
}

#user2_end {
  background-color: #f3f3f3 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.text {
  width: 557px;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.text-bottom {
  position: relative;
  left: -11%;
  top: -10px;
}

.text-bottom .user-name {
  width: 166px;
  height: 18px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #ff5d5d;
}

.text-bottom .time {
  width: 75px;
  height: 9px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 0;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #333333;
}

.timestamp {
  position: relative;
  left: -30%;
}
```

```html
<!---------------First Message------------------------>

<div class="chat-log user1" id="user1">
  <ul>
    <li class="avatar"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" alt="Mygel van Trable"></li>
    <li class="message">
      <div class="message-box">
        <p class="text">Hi Charlie! It was good meeting you for coffee the other day. I would love to talk more about your autonomous car start up! Here’s my email: webtrabel@email.com</p>
        <ul class='text-bottom'>
          <li class="user-name">Mygel van Trable</li>
          <li class="timestamp">
            <ul>
              <li class="clock-icon">
              </li>
              <li class="time">
                <p>1:41PM</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--------------------- Next Message ------------------->

<div class="chat-log" id='user2'>
  <ul>
    <li class="avatar"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000" alt="Charlie Hemn"></li>
    <li class="message">
      <div class="message-box">
        <p class="text">Thanks, Mygel! It was a pleasure chatting with you as well. You may also be interested in learning more about my new cryptocurrency start up, Goldhill LLC!</p>
        <ul class='text-bottom'>
          <li class="timestamp">
            <ul>
              <li class="clock-icon">
              </li>
              <li class="time">
                <p>1:46PM</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="user-name">Charlie Hemn</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!----------------- Next Message ------------------>
<div class="chat-log" id="user1">
  <ul>
    <li class="avatar"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" alt="Mygel van Trable"></li>
    <li class="message">
      <div class="message-box">
        <p class="text">I recently started a cryptocurrency start up as well! I’ll definitely read through the whitepaper posted on the Goldhill website and get back to you!</p>
        <ul class='text-bottom'>
          <li class="user-name">Mygel van Trable</li>
          <li class="timestamp">
            <ul>
              <li class="clock-icon">
              </li>
              <li class="time">
                <p>1:50PM</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!----------------- Next Message ------------------->

<div class="chat-log" id='user2'>
  <ul>
    <li class="avatar"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000" alt="Charlie Hemn"></li>
    <li class="message">
      <div class="message-box" id="user2_end">
        <p class="text">Sounds good to me! Looking forward to hearing from you - Charlie.</p>
        <ul class='text-bottom'>

          <li class="timestamp">
            <ul>
              <li class="clock-icon">
              </li>
              <li class="time">
                <p>2:03PM</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="user-name">Charlie Hemn</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide all of the needed CSS because at the moment it is missing classes such as `chat-log`. That means we can't recreate your page as you are seeing it.

Comment: Just added enough CSS for the entire chat. Hope that helps.

Comment: That still doesn't seem to be enough. Can you put everything into a snippet (the icon with the <> in the editor view). That way you can check that it will run online and look the same as you have it. You may be missing some files such as bootstrap etc.

Comment: @Vega 3&4 are not the cause of the missing arrows! What matters is that the CSS code belongs to 1&2 and should be part of them regardless.

Comment: @RobKwasowski All of my CSS has been added and there is no Bootstrap.

Comment: I have added your code into a snippet and when you run it you can see that it does not look like your image so there is something missing.

Comment: I can't supply the images.

Comment: Initial inspection with console shows that `top: 61%;` in css `#user2 ul li.message .message-box:after {` is messing it up. Try to work around it.

Comment: @Nik I don't understand how #user2 is messing it up. I have commented that code out and still not getting results.

Comment: You are duplicating ids. Don't. Use classes instead.

Comment: No no, Not `#user2` its the `top: 61%` with `position:absolute;` is messing it up which is written in css of `#user2 ul li.message .message-box:after`. When we say position absolute, it will take all elements having this css to at same place. so in your case i believe the two arrows are being displayed at same place, i.e. `top:61%; left: 66.1%;`. Same thing happening with `#user1 ul li.message .message-box:after`.  here is the position ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: The solution is to copy the code and set it to `:before` and change the `top` position.